# Use the Radon-Nikodym theorem to show existence of conditional expectations in a $\sigma$-finite measure space

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

## The following material comes from the book written by Wheeden and Zygmund.

[image]

## [image]

According to the hint, one can solve the problem by applying the well-known theorem to the indefinite integral. However, with the theorem applied, I only found a unique $f_0$ so that
$$\int f\mathrm{d}\mu=\int f_0\mathrm{d}\mu,$$
a result far from the desired one
$$\int fg\mathrm{d}\mu=\int f_0g\mathrm{d}\mu.$$
Is there anything I missed? How do I incorporate $g$ into the integrand? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get more than  just $\int f d\mu=\int f_0 d\mu$ from the theorem. You get $\int_E f d\mu=\int_E f_0 d\mu$ for every set $E$ in $\Sigma_0$. This gives $\int fg d\mu=\int f_0 g d\mu$ whenever $g$ is of the form $I_E$ with $E$ in $\Sigma_0$. Now take linear combinations and limits to prove the same for all $g$ measurable w.r.t. $\Sigma_0$ for which the integrals are finite.

Comment: Is $I_E$ the indicator function of $E$? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, $I_E$ is the indicator of $E$.